# Click event in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

i am programming in Visual Studio 2013, c# winform. Is it posible to choose click event for each button in FLP? Im trying to do something  like Steam Library, I already did a lot of things and it now looks like i want to.

[This is how it looks (adding)](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2yxrx3p.jpg)

[This is how it looks (library)](http://oi62.tinypic.com/t7bhqu.jpg)

(sorry, im not able to add images)

But i don't know how to open choosed game when you click on a button in FLP (in library). 
        This is how my code looks:

```
private void btnTest_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
             {
            if (textBox2.Text != "")
                {
                    Button btn = sender as Button;
                    Button btnNew = new Button();
                    btnNew.Text = "";
                    btnNew.Height = 108;
                    btnNew.Width = 230;
                    btnNew.Image = new Bitmap(textBox1.Text);
                    btnNew.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                    flpContainer.Controls.Add(btnNew);
                    btnNew.Click += btnNew_Click;
                    counter1++;
                    label1.Text = counter1.ToString(); //label1 is that "Number of games in library:"
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Game was succesfully added to library!");
                }
            else if (textBox2.Text == "")
                {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You didn't choosed exe file!");
                }
             }
        if (textBox1.Text =="")
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You didn't choosed image!");
            }
    }



    private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(textBox2.Text); //textbox2 is the path to exe file, but it change when you want to add another game to library
        }
```

But how to do different click event for each button in FlowLayoutPanel? 
Thank you for answers.

EDIT: I want to do that, when you click on a button in library it will open that game (program).

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Upload your images to some good site, eg: Tinypic.com or Imgur.com, I cannot view the images in your links.

Comment: Answer depends upon what you want to do in that click event. Give some specific example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the required information in `Tag` property for future use and get the job done.

```
Button btnNew = new Button();
btnNew.Text = "";
btnNew.Height = 108;
btnNew.Width = 230;
btnNew.Image = new Bitmap(textBox1.Text);
btnNew.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
flpContainer.Controls.Add(btnNew);
btnNew.Click += btnNew_Click;
btnNew.Tag = textBox2.Text;// <--Store it in Tag
```

Then use it in `Click` event

```
private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    Process.Start((string)clickedButton.Tag); 
}
```